# Express displaying mongodb documents in Jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm learning Node, Express, Jade & Mongodb. I'm unable to display my mongodb documents in jade. I'm unable to figure it out on my own. I'm successfully logging all documents using console.log and it display all the documents correctly. Please no mongoose or other solutions. Just how to build on this code. I already connected to the db, displayed all documents in terminal. How to be able to pass it to Jade and display it in view.jade?
Thanks.

Here is my app.js code

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



// Mongodb Example http://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    //Insert data into mongodb db. If the collection doesn't exist, it will be created with the first inserted document
    db.collection('employee').insertOne({
        number : 17,
        name: "aaa"
    });


    //Updating Documents in a collection
    db.collection('employee').updateOne(
    {"name": "New Employee"}, {$set: {"name": "AA"}}
    );

    //Deleting Documents in a collection
    db.collection('employee').deleteOne(
        { "name": "name" }

    );
    // no need to pass a second parameter. Just the name of the field to be deleted. 

    //Querying for data in mongodb db .
    var cursor = db.collection('employee').find();
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
   //console.log(doc)
    });

    console.log("connected");
    db.close();
});






var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();








// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

Here is my index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router()


//the global str variable is accessable from anywhere and logging the db.collection but how I pass it to jade?
var str = "";


/* GET home page. and iterate, display the collection to console log. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var str = db.collection('employee').find();
        str.each(function (err, doc) {
                console.log(doc);   
        });  


        //How to pass the .db.collection documents to Jade?


        res.render('index');
    });
});
```

Here is my index.jade file

```
    extends layout

block content
  h1= title
```

Comment: Some basic questions I must ask: Do you have `mongod` running in a separate terminal so you have a database process to connect to?  This is necessary for mongoDB to work.

Comment: Yes, I logged all the db.collection.find() to the terminal screen and able to see all documents.

Comment: Okay great, Let me finish this answer modification and maybe get you rolling in the right direction again.

Comment: We must simply change the jade file a bit to accept an iterative input, and send a JSON-shaped package to the `view.jade` file by `res.render('index', {"results" : mongo_results } )`  Please see the updated answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/  Has useful information for view.jade files

index.js needs an array to hold the mongo results:

```
 var results_from_mongo = [];
```

and everytime we get a result from the query, let's push it onto the array (array language for "insert an element into the array")

```
  results_from_mongo.push(doc); //Push result onto results_array
```

then we must simply send it along to res.render:

```
  res.render('index', {"results": results_from_mongo });
```

So in your `index.js` file

```
/* GET home page. and iterate, display the collection to console log. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';

    var results_from_mongo = [];

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var str = db.collection('employee').find();
        str.each(function (err, doc) {
                console.log(doc);   
                results_from_mongo.push(doc); //Push result onto results_array
        });  

        //now we have a results array filled like this:
        // results_from_mongo = ["some string", "some string", "some string"]
       //so let's pass them to the jade file to render them.

      res.render('index', {"results": results_from_mongo });
```

//this will pass the data in JSON format to the JADE file called 'index' (index.jade)

The data at this point looks like

```
    { "results" : ["some string", "some string", "some string"] }
```

and in index.jade we can do something like

```
extends layout

block content
h1= title
h2= "results from mongo:"
select
  each mongo_result, i in results
    div Result #{i} #{mongo_result}
```

Comment: That was informative answer. I learnt about Jade.render. Thank you. However, I still don't understand how to pass mongodb documents to Jade?

Comment: Sova: I'm 67 years old and challenging myself learning how to code. So, if you have time,  be kind and explain by code so I can learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: 67? Way to go!  You got it.  Let me find some nice examples.

Comment: Also, English is not my mother tongue. So forgive all typo and grammar mistakes :)

Comment: Sova, Thank you so much. I got the gist of what we're doing. I like it.

Comment: Only problem when I try it, the index page shows the h2 and no data.

Comment: So when I look at the jade file, where mongo_result comes from?

Comment: Is it suppose to be result in results? Very curious to understand this. I read the jade documents on the site. But where the mongo_result comes from?

Answer (score 1):

The jade (now pug) file needs to be set up to show a table, if you want to send an array from the database to be displayed as html. Here is the relevent code that I use for my table layout in a sample index.pug file.

```
table
    thead
      tr
        th Flight Date
        th Tail Number
        th Origin
        th Destination
        th Dep
        th Arr
    tbody
      each mongo_result, i in results
        tr
          td= mongo_result.flight_date
          td= mongo_result.tail_num
          td= mongo_result.origin_airport_code
          td= mongo_result.dest_airport_code
          td= mongo_result.dep_time
          td= mongo_result.arr_time
```

In this example, under the table header thead, I am setting up the captions for the header row of the table. Then under tbody, I am specifying the actual data I want pug to pull from each row of the array that is pushed to it. Pug is very sensitive to indentation with white space characters: it requires it. So you need to pay close attention to indentation or the results won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the db() method to handle the collection:

```
var data = [];

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';   // do not put db in url, EmployeeDB
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("EmployeeDB");
        dbo.collection("employee").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            data = result;
            db.close();
            });
        }); 
        res.render('index',{ data_employee : data });
    });
});
```

And you must update your index.jade (or index.pug) file:

```
extends layout

block content
  div.main
    table
      thead
        tr
          th name
          th surname
      tbody
        each data in data_employee
          tr
            td= data.name
            td= data.surname
```