# Empty result when querying MongoDB database in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I appologise for the horrendous title for this submission but I have been tearing my hair out for at least 8 hours now trying to solve this.

I initially took some guidance from sova's result on Express displaying mongodb documents in Jade [Express displaying mongodb documents in Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298618/express-displaying-mongodb-documents-in-jade)

However whenever I try and do the query it fails.

my index.js code is this.

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/quizmaster';

var results_from_mongo = [];

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    var str = db.collection('qmquestions').find();
    str.each(function (err, doc) {
            //console.log(doc);
            results_from_mongo.push(doc);
            console.log(results_from_mongo) //Push result onto results_array
    });

    //now we have a results array filled like this:
    // results_from_mongo = ["some string", "some string", "some string"]
   //so let's pass them to the jade file to render them.
  res.render('test', {results_from_mongo : results_from_mongo });
  });
});
```

My test.jade code is this

```
block content
h1= title
h2= "results from mongo:"
select
  each results_from_mongos, i in results_from_mongo
    option(value=i) #{results_from_mongos}
```

I have even tried the pug variation of this (test.jade)

```
        table
            thead
                tr
                    th Question name
                    th Question
                    th Answer
            tbody
                each results_from_mongo, i in results
                    tr
                        td= results_from_mongo.questionTitle
                        td= results_from_mongo.question
                        td= results_from_mongo.answer
```

The db.collections.find direct from MongoDB result is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58af574c4fef02081c32da2f"), "question" : { "questionTitle" : "Test", "question" : "Test", "answer" : "Test" } }
```

I have just tried so many different ways of trying to get it but all it equals is an empty result no matter what I do if anybody could help me out on this I would be greatly appreciated as I am just ripping my hair out on this and I feel it must be something so simple which I am missing. If anymore code is needed then I will edit the post with the code asked for.

Comment: What happen if you request your controller with curl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index.js seems to be incomplete, but the biggest issue was that you didn't have a callback for the `.find()` call for mongo. Looking at the docs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb - it seems as though they use `.toArray()` which takes a callback. You need to place your `res.render` inside of that callback so that it gets executed after mongo returns results.

As of now you are executing `res.render()` when mongo hasn't gotten any data yet, due to the asynchronous nature of node.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost/quizmaster';
  //var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/quizmaster';

  var results_from_mongo = [];

  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    //var str = db.collection('qmquestions').find();
    var str = db.collection('qmquestions').find({}).toArray(function (err, docs){
      if(err){
        return res.send('error')
      }
      console.log(docs)
      //return res.render('test', {results_from_mongo : results_from_mongo });
      return res.render('test', {results_from_mongo : docs });
    })// callback
    //str.each(function (err, doc) {
    //  //console.log(doc);
    //  results_from_mongo.push(doc);
    //  console.log(results_from_mongo) //Push result onto results_array
    //});

    //now we have a results array filled like this:
    // results_from_mongo = ["some string", "some string", "some string"]
    //so let's pass them to the jade file to render them.
  });
});

app.listen('3030', function(){
  console.log("listening on 3030")
})
```

views/test.pug

```
block content
  h1= title
  h2= "results from mongo:"
  select
      // each results_from_mongos, i in results_from_mongo
      each results_from_mongos, i in results_from_mongo
            option(value=i) #{results_from_mongos}
  ul
    each item in results_from_mongo
      li= item.question.questionTitle
```

Comment: Yeah some of the things I forgot to add into the index.js like the view engine etc.. just because I was totally stressed but thank you that works :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the method toArray After your find method call. As This:

```
collection(...).find().toArray(function(err,doc)=>
//Do what you want 
)
```